# Change paper size in winedt

Tags: paper-size, winedt

I am using sig-alternate-2013 (http://www.sheridanprinting.com/typedept/sig-alternate-2013.cls), which is supposed to print in US letter page size (8.5x11 inches), but I am now printing in A4 size (21x29.7 cm), how should I change it?

I am currently using WinEdt 8, there is some suggestions here:
http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a5
but I can't get it work.

Comment: So you want to change to A4 or do you want to change to US Letter?

Comment: WinEdt is only your editor and has nothing to do with the paper size (or fonts or …). For options regarding the paper size refer to the manual for the used class or use a package like »[geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)«.

Comment: Do you use TeXLive or MiKTeX?

Answer (score 1):

To get letter paper try this:

```
\paperwidth=8.5in
\paperheight=11in
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

which should work with most engines/drivers.